# How do I get the status of a long running operation when calling the Dialogflow gRPC API?

Tags: api, rpc, grpc, dialogflow-es, long-running-processes

Many Dialogflow RPC methods return a [`Operation`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operation) message/object which represents a long running operation.  How do I check on the status of the operation and retrieve the result if the operation is completed?

Dialogflow gRPC methods that return an operation:

- [export agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.ExportAgent-table)
- [import agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.ImportAgent-table)
- [restore agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.RestoreAgent-table)
- [train agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agents.TrainAgent-table)
- Batch operations for [intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#intents) and [entity types](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#entitytypes)

Answer (score 0):

The getOperation RPC method is used to get the status and response from a long running operation from methods that return an operation like export/import/restore/train agent and batch methods.

Here is the documentation for calling getOperation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation